# Debugging Xamarin.iOS project without physical mac

Tags: debugging, xamarin, xamarin.ios

My idea is to use macincloud to build xamarin project. And I'd like to debug it also.
[On xamarin's site](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debugging_in_xamarin_ios/) it's written that "Xamarin.iOS applications can be debugged with the built-in debugger in Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio." But it's still not clear if the device, for example iPad can be connected to Windows machine? Or It has to be connected to Mac only?

Comment: My 2cents: We use remote Mac Pros (the cylindrical $10k desktops) to create dozens of VMs for developers and use "USB over Network/Ethernet/Internet" to share those connections back the Windows' developers. I do not know if MacInCloud offers anything like that, or if your Internet bandwidth/latency is good enough to offer a workable experience. In the end, if you are doing serious iOS development, local physical devices for testing are needed, Mac Minis start at $500 and it does not take long to justify that price when you are paying per hour/month for a remote Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Device has to be connected to the Mac. If we are connecting to a mac remotely, we can use a Simulator and and view the result using a RDP client like TeamViewer. I'm not sure if that is possible with MainCloud. You can also go for Xamarin Test Cloud if that is feasible for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to deploy to device and debug with MacinCloud. You can however launch a simulator and debug your app inside the emulator.

If you want to deploy to your ipad you can use publish your app with TestFlight service and install TestFlight builds on your iPad.

See more details at [Developing iOS Apps in Visual Studio with MacinCloud](https://birdsbits.wordpress.com/2015/12/05/developing-ios-apps-in-visual-studio-with-macincloud/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways how to do it. First one is more proper but it's in preview version - Microsoft introduced [Xamarin Live Player](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/).

Second way is to have your own virtual machine of macOS on Windows machine. Here is the [tutorial](http://bitsof.net/xamarin-ios-apps-without-physical-mac/) how to do it.